# to schedule a java program using quartz scheduler

Tags: java, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I need to run a particular program once in a week,once in a month and once in a while

```
CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/20 * * * * ?"))
        .build();
```

What all changes should be done in the above code?particularly in this part(`"0/20 * * * * ?"`))
please help

Comment: Some men live longer then others...  This question isn't very well defined. By definition, something that happens once a week automatically happens more than once a month. So do you mean that you want the job to run on every Monday *and* on the 3rd day of every month? If you want a good answer to your question, you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior..These three are run according to certain conditions.If the user want to run it only once in a week then it is triggered;if he wants to run it only once in a month then that will be executed;like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to switch between multiple schedules depending on the user's choice:

```
// Once a month (the first day at midnight)
0 0 0 1 * ? 

// Once a week (Sunday at midnight)
0 0 0 * * 1

// On a specific date (November 10, 2012)
0 0 0 10 11 ? 2012
```

You can of course change the zeroes to other values if you want to change the time. See a full guide [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use cron expression you can use the build in feature of Quartz to build the trigger, but i still believe cron expression are always small and if you are comfortable with them is always the way to go

### Weekly

```
trigger=newTrigger().withIdentity(cronTriggerDTO.getTiggerId(), "simpleGroup")
.startAt(date).withSchedule(calendarIntervalSchedule()
.withIntervalInWeeks(weekly interval in int)).build();
```

### Monthly

```
trigger=newTrigger().withIdentity(cronTriggerDTO.getTiggerId(), "simpleGroup")
.startAt(date).withSchedule(monthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR_OF_DAY,MINUTE))
.build();
```

### Once

```
trigger=newTrigger().withIdentity(cronTriggerDTO.getTiggerId(),"simpleGroup")
.startAt(date).forJob("myjob", "mygroup").build();
```